# When displaying a Jpeg, the browser is displaying it about twice the size it should be

Tags: html, css

Browser: Chrome (displaying at 100%)
Desktop Monitor: 4K

When displaying a Jpeg, the browser is displaying it about twice the size it should be. Just like it's been zoomed in. Below is the HTML code and Style Sheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Testing
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/Home.jpg" width="3840" height="2560">
    </body>
</html>

body{
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Testing
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <style>
            .body_img{
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/Home.jpg" class="body_img">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using "width: 100%" certainly works.  But, when I try to create an Image Map, it won't work because image maps work on absolute coordinates.  As far as I know, you cannot make an image map work by specifying the image width as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height attributes specifies the width and height of an image, in pixels.
See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

If sizes are not set browser shows the image by DPI if is set in image.
The size attributes can set in other units ie. pt, mm, cm, in, and % (percent). 100% is a good choice maybe.

What is the real size of your image in pixels and what DPI is set in image?

If the image has 300 DPI set, then it shows as downsized, when size attributes are not set.

Comment: My image is 3840 x 2560, and the dpi is 300.  Could this cause the problem?  I cannot use the width as a percentage because I will be using an Image Map, and it won't work with percentages, only absolute.

Comment: I changed the dpi from 300 to 72, and it had no effect.

Comment: Do you need to specify width and height attributes?
Your image resolution is higher then 4K (3840x2160). So try to set these sizes.

Comment: I tried an experiment with creating a single cell table with a width of 3840 and height of 2560 and a border of 1.  When the table is displayed, it does exactly what the Jpeg does.  It displays twice the size you would expect.  Looks like this has nothing to do with the Jpeg.  You would think something so simple would work!